# Getting std::type_index of derived class from within base constructor in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17

Please consider the following C++17 program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <typeindex>

std::optional<std::type_index> b, d;

struct B {
  B() { b = std::type_index(typeid(*this)); }

  virtual ~B() = default;
};

struct D : B {
  D() { d = std::type_index(typeid(*this)); }
};

int main() {
  D x;
  if (b.value() == d.value())
    std::cout << "EQ" << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << "NE" << std::endl;
}
```

It outputs `NE`.

So it seems that during construction of the base class typeid returns the info about B and not D.

That is by design, right?  (Why was it designed this way?  The implementation knows at runtime what derived class it is constructing that B is a base class subobject of doesn't it?)

Is there any way to get the type_index of the derived class from within the constructor of B?

Comment: You could leverage [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to pass that information explicitly to the base class.

Answer (score 3):

> So it seems that during construction of the base class typeid returns the info about B and not D.

Yes. Because it's not a `D` yet. It only becomes a `D` when `D`'s constructor starts (and only fully enters its lifetime when `D`'s constructor ends).

This is no different from the behavior of `virtual` calls from within base class constructors: they will only call the virtual methods of classes whose constructors have started. Any form of dynamic type operations within a constructor only works for that particular type, not any derived class types that have yet to begin their constructors.